# port forwarding kubernetes issue

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, fabric8

I am running into a port forwarding issue with my service. The DB starts off via deployment YAML, and when my tomcat that is started manually tries to use it, it gets the connection but after 2 mins the DB connection is lost. Also, I can't log in to my DB server as well. How can I troubleshoot?

Below is my exact code:

```
LocalPortForward portForward = kClient.services().inNamespace(DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)
                    .withName(serviceName).portForward(port, port);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Could this be due to thread invoking port forward getting killed? Please have a look at our PortForwardExample : https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/PortForwardExample.java

Comment: I did kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} port-forward deployment/mycomponent-deployment 8081:8081 and it worked.

Comment: In your PortForwardExample code above you used pod and I am using service/deployment. Do you think it matters?                                                                            
<code>apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: db-service
  name: db-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "8081"
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
    - name: "8000"
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: db-service
status:
  loadBalancer: {}<code>